# can't able choose file in file manager by using OkHttp3

Tags: android, web-services, file, upload, server

I'm try to create an application where i have to upload any file not more than 16-20 mb. I am using OkHttpClient3 but my main problem it will take file with simple names such as a.mp4,b.jpg etc etc. but it can't choose file like `hello world 12.mp4` what code should be put in 
       `RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f).` 
my code is.

```
public  void enable_button(){
        choosefile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new MaterialFilePicker()
                        .withActivity(ShowStudent.this)
                        .withRequestCode(10)
                        .start();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 100 && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            enable_button();
        }else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            progress = new ProgressDialog(ShowStudent.this);
            progress.setTitle("Uploading");
            progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progress.show();

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    File f  = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));
                    String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());
                    String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);
                    RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                            .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                            .build();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("http://onsitesupport.info/diary/uploadproject.php")
                            .post(request_body)
                            .build();
                    try {
                        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                            throw new IOException("Error : "+response);
                        }
                        progress.dismiss();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }
    private String getMimeType(String path) {
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
```

and i getting ths exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3122
              Process: com.kliff.studentteacherportal, PID: 29436
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface    method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
                  at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:177)
                  at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:90)
                  at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:297)
                  at okhttp3.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:51)
                  at com.kliff.studentteacherportal.ShowStudent$2.run(ShowStudent.java:100)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.kliff.studentteacherportal.ShowStudent has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{26acab10 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,322} that was originally added here
                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:458)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:311)
                 at com.kliff.studentteacherportal.ShowStudent.onActivityResult(ShowStudent.java:91)
                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6294)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3873)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3920)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:182)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 5659
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface    method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference`. So your variable is `null`. Check before use. And find out why it is `null` . It is on line `(ShowStudent.java:91)` according your logcat.

Comment: @greenapps some of the files are uploaded to server but not other... another problem is if file size is large then progress bar does not dismiss even if file is uploaded. this problem only occurs with large size files i am new to Android. please help me

Comment: You should solve that NullPointer problem first. I wonder why you did not even name it. Dont cry for help. I gave you already help but you neglected it. Why?

Comment: `it can't choose file like hello world 12.mp4`. Do you mean that it cannot choose files with spaces in the file names? Then please tell how you choose files. With what? Unclear who is choosing.

Comment: @greenapps you are right it can't choose file with space but i solved my problem by replacing `String mimeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName()); RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType),f);

Comment: @greenapps there is another problem occurs now progress dialog close for small size file but it keep loaading for large size file .. i checked on server file is completely uploaded but still its loading

Comment: `you are right it can't choose file with space `.Sorry, I think you can choose them with that file picker. But delermining the mime type from such a filename with spaces fails.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh it's the solution! thank you. but it would be better to post as an answer for others to find it !

Comment: @li2 ok i'm posting answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I figure out,  it can't choose file with space but i solved my problem by replacing

```
String mimeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName()); 
RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType),f);`
```